# View [post.create] not found. Error in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes

I don't know what's the deal here.
My view is named `post.create.blade.php` and is in the views folder.
The route is:

```
Route::get('post/create',['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PostController@create']);
```

The post controller is returning the view along some data like this:

```
return view('post.create', ['results' => $results]);
```

so when I navigate to `myproject/post/create` I am getting:

**InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [post.create] not found.**

I already tried `php artisan config:cache` and nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the view to `create.blade.php` and put it to the `/resources/views/post` firectory.

Comment: I already did that and it didn't find the view nonetheless, besides I don't want to create a post directory.

Comment: The thing is Laravel treats `post.create` view as `post/create.blade.php`.

Comment: How I am returning the view is in the original post and I am doing exactly what laravel docs do as example for request validation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Comment: Yes, it's an example of a view. `post.create` is `post/create.blade.php`

Comment: There is a comment on "Displaying The Validation Errors" <!-- /resources/views/post/create.blade.php --> so it's views/post/create.blade.php

Comment: I'll use create_post.blade.php I don't want a useless post directory.

Comment: "Dot" notation may be used to reference nested views. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views

Comment: name the view create and put it inside your Views folder and in your return View use return view('create');